# S control wont allow me to select the item from the lookup

Tags: account, s-control

We have a system to create mass registration which will take us to a Scontrol page where we have a Search box in that we will enter the course number and search for it it brings a pop up window with the course but when we select it wont get selected.Please find the screen shots.
[image]

course number:
[image]

Course pop up:

[image]

From the above screen screen shots when we select the course number from the popup it should selected to the course field. But it is not getting selected we are just clicking on it but it wont select.

S-control Code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"> 
<html> 
<head> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252"> 
<title>Course Lookup</title> 
<script>window.opener.parent.DynamicCss.writeCss('25.0', document);</script> 
<!-- 
<link href="/sCSS/13.0/1213640181000/Theme2/default/ie7/elements.css" media="handheld,print,projection,screen,tty,tv" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 
<script type="text/javascript">try { DynamicCss.addCssUrl('/sCSS/13.0/1213640181000/Theme2/default/ie7/elements.css', 'handheld,print,projection,screen,tty,tv');} catch(e) {}</script> 
<link href="/sCSS/13.0/1213640181000/Theme2/default/ie7/common.css" media="handheld,print,projection,screen,tty,tv" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 
<script type="text/javascript">try { DynamicCss.addCssUrl('/sCSS/13.0/1213640181000/Theme2/default/ie7/common.css', 'handheld,print,projection,screen,tty,tv');} catch(e) {}</script> 
<link href="/sCSS/13.0/1213640181000/Theme2/default/ie7/setup.css" media="handheld,print,projection,screen,tty,tv" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 
<script type="text/javascript">try { DynamicCss.addCssUrl('/sCSS/13.0/1213640181000/Theme2/default/ie7/setup.css', 'handheld,print,projection,screen,tty,tv');} catch(e) {}</script> 
<link href="/sCSS/13.0/1213640181000/Theme2/default/ie7/layoutdnd.css" media="handheld,print,projection,screen,tty,tv" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 
<script type="text/javascript">try { DynamicCss.addCssUrl('/sCSS/13.0/1213640181000/Theme2/default/ie7/layoutdnd.css', 'handheld,print,projection,screen,tty,tv');} catch(e) {}</script> 
<link href="/sCSS/13.0/1214257371000/Theme2/ie7/dStandard.css" media="handheld,print,projection,screen,tty,tv" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 
<script type="text/javascript">try { DynamicCss.addCssUrl('/sCSS/13.0/1214257371000/Theme2/ie7/dStandard.css', 'handheld,print,projection,screen,tty,tv');} catch(e) {}</script> 
<link href="/sCSS/13.0/1214257371000/Theme2/00DR00000004tMK/005R0000000M95f/ie7/dCustom0.css" media="handheld,print,projection,screen,tty,tv" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 
<script type="text/javascript">try { DynamicCss.addCssUrl('/sCSS/13.0/1214257371000/Theme2/00DR00000004tMK/005R0000000M95f/ie7/dCustom0.css', 'handheld,print,projection,screen,tty,tv');} catch(e) {}</script> 
--> 

<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/functions.js"></script> 
<script src="/soap/ajax/13.0/connection.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function pageInit() { 
var nameSearch = window.opener.document.getElementById("course_search").value; 
var assessmentType = window.opener.document.getElementById("assessment_type").value; 
queryCourses(nameSearch, assessmentType); 
} 

//query all courses and place in an array 
function queryCourses(nameSearch, assessmentType) { 
emptyTable(); 
var search = "%" + nameSearch + "%"; 
var assTypeFilter = "AND (Course_Type__c = '" + assessmentType + "'"; 

if (assessmentType == "In House") { 
assTypeFilter += " OR Course_Classification__c IN ('In House','Both'))"; 
} else { 
assTypeFilter += ")"; 
} 

queryString = "SELECT Id, Name, Course_Number__c FROM Course__c WHERE (Name LIKE '" + search 
+ "' OR Course_Number__c LIKE '" + search 
+ "') AND (Effective_Date__c = null OR Effective_Date__c <= TODAY) " 
+ assTypeFilter + " ORDER BY Course_Number__c LIMIT 50"; 
var courseQuery = sforce.connection.query(queryString); 

document.getElementById("trLoading").style.display = "none"; 
showErrorMsg(courseQuery.getArray("records").length > 49); 

for (i = 0; i < courseQuery.getArray("records").length; i++) { 
var course = courseQuery.getArray("records")[i]; 
addRow(course.Id, course.Course_Number__c, course.Name); 
} 
} 

//function to populate table to select contractor 
function addRow(item1, item2, item3) { 
// assign long reference to shorter var name 
var theTable = document.getElementById("myTable"); 
// append new row to the end of the table 
var newRow = theTable.insertRow(theTable.rows.length); 
// give the row its own ID 
newRow.id = newRow.uniqueID; 

// declare cell variable 
var newCell; 
// cell insertion 
newCell = newRow.insertCell(0); 
newCell.id = newCell.uniqueID; 
newCell.innerHTML = item2; 
str = "<a href=\"javascript:choose(\'" + item1 + "\')\" >" + item2 + "</a>"; 
newCell.innerHTML = str; 
newCell = newRow.insertCell(1); 
newCell.id = item1; 
newCell.innerHTML = item3; 
} 

function emptyTable() { 
var table = document.getElementById("myTable"); 
while (table.rows.length > 2) 
table.deleteRow(-1) 
} 

function showErrorMsg(bool) { 
if (bool) 
document.getElementById("maxRowError").style.display = ""; 
else 
document.getElementById("maxRowError").style.display = "none"; 
} 
</script> 
</head> 

<body class="lookupTab LookupResultsFrame" onload="pageInit();"> 
<div class="lookup"> 
<div class="bPageTitle"> 
<div class="ptBody secondaryPalette"> 
<div class="content"> 
<img src="/s.gif" alt="" class="pageTitleIcon" title /> 
<h1>Lookup</h1> 
</div> 
</div> 
</div> 
<div class="pBody"> 
<label for="lksrch">Search</label><input id="lksrch" maxlength="80" name="lksrch" size="20" type="text" /> 
<input value=" Go! " class="btn" name="go" title="Go!" onclick="javascript:queryCourses(document.getElementById('lksrch').value, window.opener.document.getElementById('assessment_type').value);" type="submit" /> 
<div class="bDescription">You can use &quot;*&quot; as a wildcard next to other characters to improve your search results. 
For example, &quot;ad*&quot; returns all records with a word in one of the searched fields that begins with &quot;ad&quot;.</div> 
</div> 
<br> 
<div class="errorMsg" style="display: none" id="maxRowError"> 
The search returned more than the maximum number of rows (50). Please refine your search criteria.</div> 

<div class="listRelatedObject lookupBlock"> 
<div class="bPageBlock secondaryPalette"> 
<div class="pbHeader"></div> 
<div class="pbBody"> 
<table id="myTable" class="list" border="0" cellspacing="0" 
cellpadding="0"> 
<tr class="headerRow"> 
<th>Code</th> 
<th>Course Name</th> 
</tr> 
<tr id="trLoading"> 
<td colspan="2">Please wait...</td> 
<tr> 
</table> 
</div> 
<div class="pbFooter secondaryPalette"> 
<div class="bg"></div> 
</div> 
</div> 
</div> 
<div class="listElementBottomNav"></div>    
</div> 

</body> 

<script type="text/javascript"> 
// function to populate the currency fields 
function choose(id) { 
if (window.opener && !window.opener.closed) { 
//upon selection make sure class and course info are cleared first 
window.opener.resetCourseClassComp(); 
window.opener.resetDiscounts2(); 
var courseName = eval("document.getElementById('" + id + "').innerHTML"); 
window.opener.setElement("course_name", courseName); 
window.opener.setElement("courseID", id); 
if (window.opener.document.getElementById("assessment_type").value != "In House") { 
var basePrice = "0.00"; 
var earlyBirdPrice = "0.00";    
var subTotal = "0.00"; 
var taxRate = 0.0; 
var colesPrice = "0.00"; 
var taxCode = "GST"; 

//derive baseprice, gst & subtotal 
if (window.opener.document.getElementById("assessment_type").value == "Credit Transfer") { 
basePrice = "150.00" 
subTotal = basePrice; 
} else { 
queryString = "SELECT Id, " + 
" Name, " + 
" Base_Price__c, " + 
" Total_Amount__c, " + 
" GST__C, " + 
" Course_Number__c, " + 
" Coles_Price__c, " + 
" CurrencyIsoCode, " + 
" Early_Bird_Price__c " + 
" FROM Course__c WHERE Id='" + id + "'"; 
var courseQuery = sforce.connection.query(queryString); 
var course = courseQuery.getArray("records")[0]; 
if (course.Base_Price__c) 
basePrice = parseFloat(course.Base_Price__c).toFixed(2); 

if (course.Early_Bird_Price__c) 
earlyBirdPrice = parseFloat(course.Early_Bird_Price__c).toFixed(2); 

if (course.Total_Amount__c) 
subTotal = parseFloat(course.Total_Amount__c).toFixed(2); 

taxRate = course.GST__c / 100.0; 

if (course.Coles_Price__c) 
colesPrice = parseFloat(course.Coles_Price__c).toFixed(2); 

if (course.CurrencyIsoCode != "AUD"){   
queryString = "SELECT Id, " + 
" Tax_Type__r.Tax_Code_1__c, " + 
" Tax_Type__r.Tax_Rate_1__c, " + 
" Tax_Rate_1_Current__c, " + 
" Tax_Code_1__c, " + 
" Tax_1__c " + 
" FROM Class__c WHERE Course_Name__c = '" + id + "'"; 
var classResult = sforce.connection.query(queryString); 
var classes = classResult.getArray("records"); 
if(classes.length > 0) 
{ 
if(classes[0].Tax_Type__r != null) 
{ 
taxRate = (classes[0].Tax_Type__r.Tax_Rate_1__c + 0.0)/ 100.0 
taxCode = classes[0].Tax_Type__r.Tax_Code_1__c; 
} 
} 
}   
window.opener.setElement("course_search", course.Course_Number__c); 
} 
window.opener.setElement("courseEBprice", earlyBirdPrice); 
window.opener.setElement("course_base_price", basePrice); 
window.opener.setElement("coursebaseprice", basePrice); 
window.opener.setElement("coursetotalprice", subTotal); 
window.opener.setElement("taxrate", taxRate);   
window.opener.setElement("taxcode", taxCode); 
window.opener.setElement("colesbaseprice", colesPrice); 

window.opener.updateTotal(); 
window.opener.setElement("payment_method", "none"); 
window.opener.setLocationPickList();    
} 
} 
window.close(); 
} 
</script> 
</html>
```

This is the error message I get when i checked Console Error Warnings in browser.
[image]

Comment: Wait... You're using nearly two-decade-old technology? Have you considered upgrading to Visualforce?

Comment: @sfdcfox we did not got any approval from business owners on this upgrade yet. Do you think this might be the reason why it is not working?

Comment: Okay, so there's some issues with this code, but it has to do with the interaction of this page with the parent page you're calling it from. I apologize, but I think we need the other S-Control's code.

Comment: The code which i have posted is the S-control Code and can you tell are you looking for course . It is the object that has lot of course records with it. This S-control will retreive the exact record based on the Number we enter in the search field

Comment: There's two pages/s-controls here. The first is the page where it shows the red-ish banner that has the psuedo-lookup field and all that, the second is the popup window. The second window manipulates the elements of the first. This was a common tactic in those days, trying to mimic standard lookup functionality. How do you access the initial page? A button or link on the account, I presume? What's the code behind that button? Where does it point to?

Comment: @sfdcfox yes i have that S-control Code but here I cannot put them since it will exceed the Character.

Comment: You can use [PasteBin](https://pastebin.com/) to post overflow code, or you can try to reduce the code that isn't the problem, though I understand that may be difficult to do in your present situation. The other page has the answers that we need, however.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70141/discussion-between-samuel-robert-and-sfdcfox).